# Symbolic links vs Hard links

Tags: symbolic-link

I just read the [manpage for symlinks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/symlink.7.html), but I still dont get it ... so hardlinks are pointers to the file/dir. Then symlink is a pointer to a pointer? Whats the use of a symlink then? Why/when should I use one over the other?