# Replace link for pictures in Nautilus "Places" with symbolic link to an external or other internal drive? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: external-hdd, symbolic-link

I have many pictures and when I open Shotwell it takes a very long time to load. I can see the Shotwell window and the progress bar though I do not see the thumbnails until after the indexing is complete. Upping to 12GB of RAM hasn't helped that much.

My guess is that part of the issue is because my pictures folder is very large and is on the same disk as my OS.

It makes sense to me that it would be much easier on my computer if LARGE files are stored on a separate disk from my OS disk.

Anyone know how I could achieve this? I want to replace the link in Nautilus **Places**, not add a bookmark.

Comment: I don't think adding the separate hard drive for pictures will help you much.

Comment: Really, and how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: To change the bookmark links see http://askubuntu.com/questions/293898/nautilus-bookmarks-are-missing-since-upgrade-to-13-04

Comment: Takkat, Thank you for the link. That is likely what I was looking for "~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks" I'll give it a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: Nah, editing "~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks" merely changes the bookmark in the bookmark listing.

Comment: I believe I have found an answer here. I was missing an edit of the fstab to add in "bind." as is discussed in this post http://askubuntu.com/a/161461/277520

Hopefully it works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documents stored on separate internal drive, Ubuntu doesn't notice on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161459/documents-stored-on-separate-internal-drive-ubuntu-doesnt-notice-on-startup)