# How to share folders inside a DualBoot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, shared-folders

I have finally decided to dual-boot my Windows 7 machine with Ubuntu.

I would like to have the same documents folder in Windows and in Ubuntu. So when I create new document with Ubuntu and copy it in the Documents folder, it would show up in Documents library in Windows 7.

Is there any way to achieve that? I don't want it synchronize (so there would be 2 copies of every single file) but that it would be the same folder, just accessible from different OS in the same machine.

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/73977/62483

Answer (score 2):

in kde you can go to "System Settings" → "Account Details" → "Paths" and set the Document  path to your windos7 path. This is possible because Ubuntu can do that. The other way round is impossible by default because windows can't. There must be something similar setting with other Windows Managers like Unity,Xfce,Gnome,...

Answer (score 1):

For my dual boot system (Win 7 - Ubuntu 12.10) I created a partition (NTFS) in Win for documents which is accessible by Ubuntu. I didn't bother resetting any paths in Win or Ubuntu, I just save files that I want accessible by both systems in that partition. This is a simple modification of what elf stated.